# javascript: identical div id twice on page

Tags: javascript

I need to figure out if I can perform the same javascript action on two identical  elements with the same ID.

I have a box that appears twice on the page with the same content:

```
<div class="my_box" id="23"> Some bit 23 </div>

<div class="my_box" id="23"> Some bit 23 </div>
```

Then I find that element: (or those?)

```
var my_box_find = document.getElementsByClassName('my_box');
```

and after some processing/calculations want to replace the innerHTML of /both/ boxes:

```
document.getElementById(my_box_find[i].id).innerHTML = 'New bit 23';
```

This is an extremely simplified example. But it works when the element I am trying to change appears only once. If it appears twice, only the first instance will be changed...

*Thinking out loud:* I supposed I could append the ID with some random number to make each box pseudo-unique... but then this will do the calculations twice unnecessarily... I want them both to update at the same time with the same information.

Comment: id's are typically only used once on a page. If you have multiples make it a class. ie- class="my_box 23". Now the div will have both classes, just space delimit them.

Comment: An ID is supposed to be just that: a unique identifier. You shouldn't ever have two elements with the same ID one one page.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

IDs **must** be unique in a page.  It is [invalid](http://www.w3.org/TR/1999/REC-html401-19991224/struct/global.html#adef-id) to have non-unique element `id`s.

If you want to operate on multiple elements, assign a class to each element and loop through the selected results.  A class may be used multiple times, and an element may be assigned multiple classes.

```
var els = document.getElementsByClassName('my_box');
for (var i = 0; i < els.length; i++) els[i].innerHTML = 'New bit 23';
```

Or, with jQuery:

```
$('.my_box').html('New bit 23');
```

Answer (score 0):

The *real* answer is that you should **make all of your IDs unique**.  Use the `data-id` attribute instead (that doesn't have to be unique).  You can even handle it in the same way then.

If you *must* have duplicate IDs, even though I doubt it, it's still possible.  You've made it even harder because `querySelectorAll` will not work with ID attributes beginning with a digit (even though they are valid in HTML5 .. ACK).  You can just check the ID attribute on `.my_box` divs anyway.

```
Array.prototype.forEach.call(document.querySelectorAll('.my_box'),
function (elem) {
    if (elem.id === '23') {
       elem.innerHTML = elem.innerHTML.replace('23', '24');
    }
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/ExplosionPIlls/39nk2/

Comment: This suggestion is really an abuse of browsers' forgiveness when it comes to parsing HTML.  The spec says the `id` attribute *must* be unique within a page; it's not possible to author a valid document which duplicates IDs.

Comment: @josh3736 did you just choose to ignore my first paragraph?

Comment: I'm talking about the second one.  Because the spec says IDs *must* (not *should*) be unique, looping through elements and comparing the `id` attribute isn't always guaranteed to work.  An implementation might reset the `id` attribute of an element if it detects a duplicate.

Comment: @josh3736 who cares if it's an abuse of browsers' forgiveness?

Comment: Because we should encourage correctness, not "here's something that works because it exploits a bug"

Comment: @josh3736 forgiveness is not a bug.  I am encouraging correctness anyway.  Are you saying we should not provide solutions in the hopes to obscure circumvention of the spec?  I even provided an alternative: use `data-id`.